# dynamically search for a div base on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html like below:

```
<input type='search' name='con_msg_srch' placeholder='Search Contact'/>
<div class='contactlist'>
    <span class='_webnn'>James Oduro</span>
</div>
<div class='contactlist'>
    <span class='_webnn'>John Doe</span>
</div>
<div class='contactlist'>
    <span class='_webnn'>Opoku Elvis</span>
</div>
```

I have written a function to search for a particular contact within  **contactlist** contact whose innerHTML of  its span children matches value of the search input.

How can I modify the **RegExp** to do the following:

1. Replace double white space in between the value of the search input
2. Able to match case sensitivity from aA-zZ
3. Should be able to match if the user type the lastname first or firstname

I really don't have much knowlege in RegExpression thats why i need help

JQuery:

```
$('input[name="con_msg_srch"]').keyup(function(){
    var value = $.trim($(this).val());
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');

    $('.contactlist').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('._webnn', this).text());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: why the down vote??..I dont want to send request to search each time on keyup thats the reason why am doing this kind of local search...cux in my real project am returning lots of contact list

Comment: just remove the `'^'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('input[name="con_msg_srch"]').keyup(function(){
    var value = $.trim($(this).val());
    var value = value.replace( /  +/g, ' ' )
    var exp = new RegExp(value, 'i');

    $('.contactlist').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('._webnn', this).text());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you..really simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You should put the innerText of span also as a value of an attribute to the span as following.

```
<div class='contactlist'>
    <span class='_webnn' data='James Oduro'>James Oduro</span>
</div>
<div class='contactlist'>
    <span class='_webnn' data='John Doe'>John Doe</span>
</div>
<div class='contactlist'>
    <span class='_webnn' data='Opoku Elvis'>Opoku Elvis</span>
</div>
```

Instead of searching based on the HTML content, now you can search the span based on the value of "data" attribute. This will simplify your search logic.

It's not necessary to have the attribute name "data". You can create attribute with any name for an HTML tag.

I hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: yeah...sure I will do it that way. Thank you